# Xamarin forms navigation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble with Xamarin forms navigation, as in, it does not work at all.

My code :

**appname.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace List
{
    public class App : Application {
        public App () {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage (new HomePage ());
        }
    }
}
```

**homepage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
namespace List
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage {
        public HomePage () {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        public void OnButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args) {
            Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailsPage ());
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is obviously to open a main page, have a button on there that goes to a second page upon press.
However this happens instead whenever the button is clicked:

**error message**

> ```
> Could not load type 'UIKit.UIView_UITextField' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS'.
> ```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit - code for DetailsPage, since this could be source of error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace List
{
    public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public DetailsPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2 - code for Xaml pages (thanks for the help everyone, I really appreciate it):

Homepage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:List" x:Class="List.HomePage">
            <ContentPage.Title>
                1
            </ContentPage.Title>
            <Button Text="Click Me!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
    </ContentPage>
```

DetailsPage.Xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="List.DetailsPage">
        <Label Text="LOL"/>
    </ContentPage>
```

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your DetailsPage.  Your navigation code is correct.

Comment: I noticed you are using Xaml. Could you please post your Xaml, as that looks to be the source of the error.

Comment: I would check you have the Xamarin Forms nuget package installed on your iOS project as well as your Forms project.

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml, the first element needs to be a layout (if you have multiple elements). I would try something similar to below and see if anything changes.

HomePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:List" x:Class="List.HomePage" Title="1">
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Click Me!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

DetailsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="List.DetailsPage">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="LOL"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Also, I noticed you were setting your title like using ContentPage.Title 1 ContentPage.Title. This is unnecessary. Just set the title directly in your ContentPage tag as I showed in the above example.

Comment: Nope still the same issue. It was worth a try though, my xml formatting was a little off.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was having the same problem as you. I came across [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/) solution of the xamarin guide.

It seems that in app.cs you need to call the `using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;`

Right above your namespace insert `[assembly:XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]`

But I really can't tell why. I'm Looking for the reason. Try to see if it resolves. In my case went well. Sorry about the bad english and the bad edit of the post, kind of new to this. But comparing all your code, it was missing this piece for you too, maybe this is the reason.

EDIT (12/01/2017) - Add

i found [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/optimizing-xamarin-forms-apps-for-maximum-performance/), that might explain why was not working, seems like the function that we are using is part of a new set for Xamarin that helps him to became faster.

I can be wrong, if I am, please correct me someone that knows better.

Answer (score -3):

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailsPage());
```

Reference: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Navigation

Comment: No same error message... From my understanding PushModalAsync and PushAsync are very similar, except with PushModalAsync you cannot go back to the previous page

Comment: PushModalAsync is supported on all pages, and not just a NavigationPage stack. It basically places a page on top of the current one (or stack), and you can go back to your previous page by using the Navigation.PopModalAsync() method.